# Accept-Encoding headers on Cloudfront serving assets from Rails 3.0.x on Heroku Cedar

Tags: encoding, heroku, gzip, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

When I use my Rails app to directly serve my assets through Heroku's Cedar stack (ie. NOT through a CDN) they get gzip'd automatically.  (See my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781039/heroku-cedar-static-assets-rails-3-0-x) on why I'm confused about this)

Now, I'm trying to set up Cloudfront to serve these assets instead, and ideally, I'd like for them to be gzip'd as well.  From what I've read, I thought that Cloudfront would pass on the `Accept` headers to my app, so they should be served up gzip'd if supported (just as they are when you make a direct request to the asset on heroku).  But this isn't the case.  The asset headers end up looking like this:

```
Age:510
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:178045
Content-Type:text/css
Date:Sun, 08 Jan 2012 18:55:13 GMT
Last-Modified:Sun, 08 Jan 2012 18:42:34 GMT
Server:nginx/0.7.67
Via:1.1 varnish, 1.0 7a0b4b3db0cc0d369fe1d6981bfb646a.cloudfront.net:11180 (CloudFront), 1.0 6af08f4042ec142b4b760ca4cd62041d.cloudfront.net:11180 (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id:2b205edf4e9ef000a31a0208ca68f4e15b746eb430cde2ba5cc4b7dff4ba41a76c24f43cf498be02,8d5863a42eea452f86831a02f3eb648b26fe07013b08b95950f15ef8ba275822e1eb3b7ed2550d01
X-Cache:Hit from cloudfront
X-Varnish:2130919357
```

There's no mention of encoding here, and when I view the plain file, it's not gzip'd.  So I'm wondering what I need to do here to get Cloudfront to request a gzip'd version of the asset from my app so that it can serve this to the client.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442011/serving-gzipped-css-and-javascript-from-amazon-cloudfront) says you need to manually gzip and upload the file, but I don't see why that should be necessary.  For one, it's annoying, and two, wouldn't it request the file the same as my browser directly?  So why wouldn't it just serve up the gzip'd file as it does by default in my app?

Any tips on getting gzip'ng working properly would be great.  I'd like to not have to manually gzip my files and upload them if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cedar served files do NOT get GZipped by the stack, Cedar only serves whatever you have in the application code. See the [documentation](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing):

> Since requests to Cedar apps are made directly to the application
>   server – not proxied through an HTTP server like nginx – any
>   compression of responses must be done within your application. For
>   Rack apps, this can be accomplished with the Rack::Deflater
>   middleware. For gzipped static assets, make sure that Rack::Deflater
>   is loaded before ActionDispatch::Static in your middleware stack.

Therefore the GZipping your seeing either is a false header, or is coming from somewhere else which.  Therefore if you've just pushed files to Cloudfront then you're just seeing the same thing.

If you're looking at serving zipped assets via CDN I would really recommend looking at bumping to Rails 3.1 and using the Asset pipeline. Not only will this give you more control over your assets bu also give you a much easier path to [serving them over a CDN](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31).

Comment: So it turns out that I had A records pointing to heroku.com rather than CNAME-ing herokuapp.com as the docs suggest.  In this case, it actually was filtering my requests through Varnish.  And it was gzipping everything.  I've changed it now and I'm going to use `Rack::Deflater` until I can actually upgrade to Rails 3.1 (which is obviously my first choice, but not possibly for me ATM)

Comment: Super, glad to be of help - feel free to tick my answer ;)

Comment: FYI I don't  think anything in that article you referenced is really necessary.  Cloudfront grabs my files passing on the Accept-Encoding header, then caches them in its CDN.  I don't see any reason why I would manually sync my assets.  First request will be slow yes, but subsequent requests will be fast and served from the CDN.  Thx again though for the tips.